# why cannot I get out of this issue and solve the problem in tensorboard?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorboard

I ended up with an error `"Abort trap: 6"` when I try to visualize the compute graph by Tensorboard. I can't just solve the issue. The error is below.

```
[libprotobuf ERROR external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor_database.cc:393] Invalid file descriptor data passed to EncodedDescriptorDatabase::Add().
[libprotobuf FATAL external/com_google_protobuf/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.cc:1367] CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type google::protobuf::FatalException: CHECK failed: GeneratedDatabase()->Add(encoded_file_descriptor, size): 
Abort trap: 6
```

Please help me out!

Comment: Try giving details of your working environment.

Comment: Thank you for replying me!. OS is mac, I make use of anaconda. I wrote some code like 'tf.compat.v1.summary.FileWriter'  and made 'logs' directory. Then, when I put 'tensorboard --logdir=~' in terminal, the error was thrown.

Comment: I knew in some websites that I should install tensorflow by pip and put 'python tensorboard --logdir=~' in terminal and something like that, and I tried them. But I didn't make it!